# Cocoapods mix pods with different deployment targets

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

My project has iOS 4.3 as its deployment target.

All my pod libraries support 4.3 but one which I also want to include, taking care off course not to use its classes on iOS 4.3 devices.

I tried using the `target` option on my Podfile as follows:

```
platform :ios, '4.3'
pod 'NBUCore'

target :MyApp do
    platform :ios, '5.0'
    pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor'
end
```

Which creates the usual `libPods.a` with `NBUCore` and a new `libPods-MyApp.a` with `PEPhotoCropEditor`, both correctly linked to MyApp.

The problem is that there are two `.xcconfig` files, `Pods.xcconfig` and `Pods-MyApp.xcconfig`  but only one of them gets activated by Cocoapods and thus link fails because each has an incomplete `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.

I have tried with both `target :test, :exclusive => true` and `false`.

Off course I could manually modify them, use both or add `$(inherited)` flags. But then Cocoapods should take care of that. Or maybe my Podfile syntax is wrong?

Edit: Turns out that also the "Copy Pods Resources" for both Pods and Pods-MyApp would also need to be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my iOS 9.3+ project I have an iOS 11+ dependency. To make it work I:

- Set my project and Podfile to iOS 11.
- `pod install`
- Set back my project to iOS 9.3.
- In the generated Pods project set all the non-3rd party `Pods-xxx` targets to 9.3.
- Use preprocessor macros to fix any compilation issues.

**Original Answer**

It is not possible with the current Cocoapods (filed an issue [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1376)).

The solution for now is to separate Pods by deployment target:

```
platform :ios, '4.3'
pod 'NBUCore'

target :MyApp do
    platform :ios, '5.0'
    pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor'
end
```

Then "merge" the .xcconfig files.

Finally add all resources' scripts to the "Copy Pods Resources":

```
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Pods-MyApp-resources.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want. You could, however, copy [PEPhotoCropEditor's  Podfile](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor/blob/master/PEPhotoCropEditor.podspec) to your project and change `s.ios.deployment_target = '5.0'` to `s.ios.deployment_target = '4.3'`.

Then, in your `Podfile`, instead of

```
pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor'
```

do

```
pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor', :path => "CustomPodspec.podspec"
```

Comment: However some pod dependencies may still be iOS5+. Also I could change my Podfile platform to `'5.0'` and keep using it with care from my iOS 4.x project, but then other problems may arise as dependencies get resolved.